# Get type name from json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, list, object

I have object that have additional arrays inside and it looks like this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

As you can see, each array is some sort of "Type" (Activity,Connection,Object etc.)
What I need is to make list of names from all arrays and all types

So, to make complete list of names from all elements in Type arrays.

So far, my code in component regarding this object is this:

```
    ngOnInit() {

      this.codeService.get().subscribe(
              response => { this.handleSuccess( response ); },
              error => { console.error( error ); });

  }


  handleSuccess( oTypes ) {
      this.oTypes = oTypes } 

}
```

...Where for oTypes i get object with this arrays from this picture.

Comment: Looks like Javascript?

Comment: close :D Angular 2 @danopz

Comment: Ok I don't really get waht you want to achieve. Could you add your desired output?

Comment: So, i just want to go through all arrays and get names from all elements inside and put them in some list in html. U can see, ActivityType array have 20 elements, ConnectionType have 2 etc etc... Function should to through them and get names so I can have "list of names" like "Location", "Vessel", "Element", "Line" ...:) @danopz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just iterated over it a bit but looks like this is what you want to achieve.

```js
var oTypes = {
    aType: [{name: 'Name1'}, {name: 'Name2'}],
    bType: [{name: 'N3'}, {name: 'N4'}]
};

var names = [];
for (var t in oTypes) {
    if (oTypes.hasOwnProperty(t)) {
        oTypes[t].forEach(function(v){
            names.push(v.name);
        });
    }
}

// ["Name1", "Name2", "N3", "N4"]
console.log(names);
```

Comment: Yes, something like that, I just need to make it to angular 2 sintax ;) @danopz

Comment: Angular 2 is Javascript. You can just add this code into your `handleSuccess` and add names to the scope with ex. `this.names = names;`

Comment: Works like charm :D Thanks ;)